# AndroidAnnotations + cwac endless integration

Tags: android, android-annotations, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the amazing [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) framework and now trying to do infinite scrolling with [cwac-endless](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) lib. The problem is the fact the I need to subclass my Adapter to EndlessAdapter which obliges me to implement one of it's four constructors. At the same time, my former adapter was annotated with @EBean which only allows constructors with a Context parameter or void. None of the four constructors of EndlessAdapter is allowed by @EBean. Should I drop one solution or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

`EndlessAdapter` is open source. You are welcome to copy it into your project and modify it to suit.